# Tomcat 7 Connection Pool Issue

Tags: java, tomcat7, sybase

I seem to have stumbled across a weird behavior with tomcat 7 and connection pooling...

In my app, I have the following 3 data sources - connecting to the same database, but different services ( and  are the same across all 3)

```
jdbc:sybase:Tds:<db_ip_address>:<db_port>/service1
jdbc:sybase:Tds:<db_ip_address>:<db_port>/service2
jdbc:sybase:Tds:<db_ip_address>:<db_port>/service3
```

In my context.xml, I have the 3 data sources listed as a separate resource as usual, with all neccessary options set, including

```
<Resource
    name="jdbc/dbDataSource1"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    driverClassName="com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver"
    factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
    maxActive="20"
    initialSize="1"
    minIdle="5"
    maxIdle="10"

<Resource
    name="jdbc/dbDataSource2"
    <!-- Rest is same as above -->

<Resource
    name="jdbc/dbDataSource3"
    <!-- Rest is same as above -->
```

What I have noticed is, because the 3 data sources connect to the same database, tomcat only seems to be creating and using one connection pool and sharing between all 3. This can be seen at startup, where if I change initialSize to say 10, the first 2 data sources are created no problem - on the 3rd, I get an exception saying

```
java.sql.SQLException: JZ00L: Login failed. 
Examine the SQLWarnings chained to this exception for the reason(s).
```

Am I missing something obvious here on how to set up the connection pool? I have looked at the tomcat documentation and stuff related to global connection pools, however from what I can gather this seems to be related to sharing the connections between multiple apps?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Please also show the java code where you are making use of these data sources. Ideally there should be multiple DataSource configured in tomcat even if only the services changes.

Comment: I wouldn't be able to post any source code, however I do think the problem is related to the connection pooling configuration, rather than the code

Comment: Ok. So are you using same datasource name for accessing these 3 db connection?

Comment: No, in the context.xml the resources each have a unique name, I have updated my question to show what I mean

Answer (score 1):

Indeed seems to be too many idle connection. Try to increase the idle Connection properties or check whether you are closing all the opened connection.
Please refer to [this link](http://www.kangarooit.com/developer_blog/2006/11/sybase-error-jz00l-when-trying-to.php)

Comment: Yes, that could be the reason why it is failing to create all data sources.. although the main problem seems to be why does it appear to be sharing the same connection pool for all 3 resources, rather than creating a pool for each?

Comment: It should. But need to find out if it really shares same connection pool.

Comment: Is there a way to see any of the connection pool details? Unfortunately I am unable to connect a jconsole instance or anything to the machine to monitor it!

Comment: You can use `lambda probe` to check the connections and other details.

Comment: Turns out we can't connect to that server or tomcat instance at all to monitor it, which is a bit of a problem... :P

Comment: I am fairly certain that the 3 data sources are actually using the same connection pool - with initialSize set to 10 and maxActive set to 20, it fails after two data sources are created. Setting initialSize to 20, it fails after one data source. Setting initialSize to 5, all three data sources connect successfully